# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Hola amigos hace un tiempo programe una app la cual estoy retomando ahora despues de 1 año pero ha cambiando la versión del gradle 3.3 y del android studio 2.3.3 y creo que por esto me esta dando problemas al sincronizar mi aplicación.

El primer error que identifico es en el build.gradle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El segundo error de mensaje es:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

como dato antes tenia mi classpath asi.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
```

ahora esta así.

```
   dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        }
```

Este es el log:

```
2017-10-18 11:21:34,353 [67792305]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources] 
2017-10-18 11:21:34,378 [67792330]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2017-10-18 11:21:34,437 [67792389]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\sebastian.espinoza\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo3685.gradle] 
2017-10-18 11:21:34,437 [67792389]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\sebastian.espinoza\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo3685.gradle] 
2017-10-18 11:21:35,840 [67793792]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-10-18 11:21:35,931 [67793883]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 2ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-10-18 11:21:35,958 [67793910]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 27ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-10-18 11:21:36,170 [67794122]   WARN - .tools.idea.model.ManifestInfo - getMergedManifest failed Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Comment: El primer "error" en realidad es solo un Warning, en este caso debes agregar tu AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Como? el archivo AndroidManifest.xml  esta en árbol del proyecto.

Comment: El error de la imagen te lo está diciendo: al agregar `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` alguna otra librería no coincide con esta versión, sino con la que tenías antes: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'` entonces, debes poner todo a la altura de la versión 2.3.3. Si [editas tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/110387/edit) poniendo tu manifest como lo tienes y los archivos `gradle` podremos revisarlo (los datos sensibles los puedes modificar) .